# Configuration arm-unknown-elf not supported - ARM Toolchain

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, arm, gnu

I try to setup a gnu arm toochain on my Ubuntu Linux computer. I already downloaded

```
tar -xvf gcc-4.8.2.tar.bz2
tar -xvf binutils-2.24.tar.bz2
tar -xvf newlib-2.1.0.tar.gz 
tar -xvf insight-6.8.tar.bz2
```

and extracted them. I started with installing the binutils succeccfully OK. 
In my second step I intended to biuld up the first gcc bootstrap installation to compile newlib in turn (in the next step). But anyway I could not succeed the gcc installation:

```
sudo ../gcc-4.8.2/configure --target=arm-elf --prefix=/opt/gnuarm --enable-interwork --enable-multilib --enable-languages="c,c++" --enable-target-optspace --with-float=soft --with-newlib --with-headers=../newlib-2.1.0/newlib/libc/include/ --disable-nls
```

It runs until I got following error message:

```
//... a lot of checkings...
checking for clock_t... yes
checking for F_SETLKW... yes
checking if mkdir takes one argument... no
*** Configuration arm-unknown-elf not supported
make: *** [configure-gcc] Fehler 1
```

I appreciate any hints . Thanks in advance.
Sincerly Murat

Comment: See: [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/).  Building a native compiler is fairly straight forward.  However, at least start with some scripts before you try to do this by hand for a cross compiler.  Ubuntu should already have compilers; try `apt-cache search arm | grep gcc`.  You seem to have a handle on concepts, so *crosstool-ng* should get you a compiler to suit your needs quickly.

Comment: What is the intended target for your toolchain? Are you looking to build Linux code or bare metal?

Comment: You may need to specify an abi but I'd think that would be covered with the `elf` target.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok I solved it by selecting another target. The issue is that in gcc 4.7 **arm-elf** was obsolete and in 4.8 dropped. So you have to build your toolchain with an older gcc (4.6 or older) or you should select another target.

I decided to compile my toolchain for -target=arm-none-eabi (embedded application binary interface), which should fit my target. Thank you very much.

Comment: I changed my target to --target=arm-none-linux and works.

Comment: Yes, for OpenBSD 7.2 I changed `aarch64-unknown-elf` to `arm-none-eabi` by --build and --target with configure. (So, I can build gcc 4.3.4 after patch errors for floor_log2, exact_log2, ...)

Comment: P.S.: Default target `aarch64-unknown-openbsd7.2` does not work with gcc/egcc.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502045/gcc-compilation-cannot-compute-suffix-of-object-files-cannot-compile