# When compiling GCC im getting configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile See `config.log' for more details error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, glibc

Im using this code:

> BUILD_CC="gcc" CC="${XterOS_TARGET}-gcc" 
> AR="${XterOS_TARGET}-ar" 
> RANLIB="${XterOS_TARGET}-ranlib" CFLAGS="-O2" 
> glibc-2.27/configure --prefix=/usr 
> --host=${XterOS_TARGET} --build=${XterOS_HOST} 
> --disable-profile --enable-add-ons --with-tls 
> --enable-kernel=2.6.32 --with-__thread 
> --with-binutils=${XterOS}/cross-tools/bin 
> --with-headers=${XterOS}/usr/include 
> --cache-file=config.cache

and im getting this error

> configure: loading cache config.cache
> checking build system type... x86_64-cross-linux-gnu
> checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
> checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/igor/xter-os/glibc-build': configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile See` config.log' for more details

This is my config.log:
https://pastebin.com/88bwKZwu

And this is my configuration file
https://pastebin.com/AdqcShP8

Comment: Links to offsite resources are frowned upon because they are impermanent. When they rot away, the question becomes less useful and in this case pretty much useless. All information necessary to understanding a question must be in the question, preferably  in text.

Comment: `./glibc-2.27/configure: line 2623: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc: command not found` - if you are trying to cross compile glibc, you are definitely failing to specify the correct cross compiler. I don't see `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc` very often these days; it was common in the '00s but nowadays most distros AFAIK use something more akin to `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc`.

Comment: Is this answer helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502045/gcc-compilation-cannot-compute-suffix-of-object-files-cannot-compile

Comment: @mcilloni So if i use 'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc' it will work?

Comment: @IgiPaligi if you are targeting `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` and `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc` exists, yes, it should. What are you trying to do exactly? Why are you building Glibc?