# Gcc compilation "cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile" on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, gcc, raspberry-pi

GCC 12 must be installed to align with other environments. I try to install GCC 12 to my raspberry pi 400.

I installed requirements libraries.

- libgmp-dev
- libmpfr-dev
- libmpc-dev

I get GCC source.

`wget http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/software/gcc/releases/gcc-12.2.0/gcc-12.2.0.tar.gz`

Expand it and configure.

`./configure --prefix /opt/gcc12 --enable-languages=c,c++`

Build

make -j4

I got error message.

checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/user/gcc-12.2.0/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc': configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile See` config.log' for more details

I tried bing for obtain solutions. But I found nothing except likely case on Stackoverflow.
This case.
[Gcc compilation "cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502045/gcc-compilation-cannot-compute-suffix-of-object-files-cannot-compile)

Does anyone know why I get this error?